# Ajax: Posting dynamic ajaxed content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fopen

I am trying to write the content of a `div` to a new html file. The content of the `div` is being generated by ajax itself, so when I try to post the contents to a new file, all that is being written to the file is the raw html. Is there a way to write the `div` contents of the 'ajaxed in' content?

This is my ajax code:

```
$("#getSource").on('click', function(){

  headerURL = $(".header-code").attr('data-url');
  $.ajax({
    url: headerURL,
    data: "function=showCode",
    success: function(data){
      $('code #mainCode').append(data);
    }
  });

  var bufferId =$("#mainCode").html();
  $.ajax({
     type : "POST",
     url : "postCode.php",
     data: {id : bufferId},
     dataType: "html",
     success: function(data){ 
       alert("ok");  
     }
  });
});
```

my php code:

```
$handle = fopen("test.html", 'w+');
$data = $_POST['id'];
if($handle) {
    if(!fwrite($handle, $data )) {
        echo "ok";
    }
}
```

the end result of whats being written in `test.html`:

```
<div id="mainCode"></div>
```

when I really need:

```
<div id="mainCode">
  [dynamic content that is added by the user via ajax]
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code that generates the dynamic content? Are you setting `bufferId` before that code runs?

Comment: How is the Ajax call being initiated? Show the actual code for that. My guess is you are storing that into the variable and never update it wit the new content.

Comment: I just updated the above code. It is very simplified, but the principle is there. Basically, I click a button and it ajaxes in HTML from a separate php file, but at the same time, I need to write a file with that same code that is being ajaxed.

Comment: I got it working. I used .when().then() to handle the get and post ajaxes. Seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can use a deffered object returned by $.ajax to run second ajax request after the first one:

```
headerURL = $(".header-code").attr('data-url');
$.ajax({
    url: headerURL,
    data: "function=showCode",
    success: function(data){
      $('code #mainCode').append(data);
    }
}).done(
  function() {
    var bufferId =$("#mainCode").html();
    $.ajax({
       type : "POST",
       url : "postCode.php",
       data: {id : bufferId},
       dataType: "html",
       success: function(data){ 
         alert("ok");  
       }
    }); 
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue second AJAX call after first call appends content. Change JavaScritp code to:

```
$("#getSource").on('click', function(){

  headerURL = $(".header-code").attr('data-url');
  $.ajax({
    url: headerURL,
    data: "function=showCode",
    success: function(data){
      $('code #mainCode').append(data);

      // second ajax call
      var bufferId =$("#mainCode").html();
      $.ajax({
         type : "POST",
         url : "postCode.php",
         data: {id : bufferId},
         dataType: "html",
         success: function(data){ 
           alert("ok");  
         }
      });
    }
  });
});
```